# Flutter Firestore query

Tags: flutter

Please I have 20 documents coming from Firestore, but I want to show atleast 7 and use "see all" button so that when a user clicks on it, it will show all the products. Please and hint or code on how I can achieve this.. Like the picture below. Thanks.

```
getProducts(ProductNotifier productNotifier)async{
  int perPage = 7;
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("Products").limit(perPage)
      .getDocuments();

  List<Product> _productList = [];

  snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
    Product product = Product.fromMap(document.data);
    _productList.add(product);

  });

  productNotifier.productList = _productList;
}
```

Then on the View All Page I used This query but I had to used getProduct instead of getProducts to query it without the limit.

```
getProduct(ProductNotifier productNotifier)async{
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Products")
          .getDocuments();

      List<Product> _productList = [];

      snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
        Product product = Product.fromMap(document.data);
        _productList.add(product);

      });

      productNotifier.productList = _productList;
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caad0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a horizontal scrolling list view for the preview

```
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView(

                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),

                  children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {

                    YourObject object = getObject(document);

                    return Container(child : yourWidget);
                  }).toList(),
                )
                ,
              )
              ,
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable in my build widget and used for loop to load the quantity i wanted per page and used the see all button to retrieve all.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int perPage = 7;
    for(int x = perPage; x < productNotifier.productList.length; x++) {
      return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: perPage,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container()
          // ui code goes here
     }
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use limit in your firestore query.
To see all documents use below query without limit.

```
int perPage = 7; //your document size
Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection('your_collection').limit(perPage);
```

Comment: Thanks....Please I'm trying to implement it but I'm not getting it in a right way. I used
int perPage = 7; then I used QuerySnapshot snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection("products").limit(perPage).getDocuments. it loaded the 7 alright and when I press the see all and change the firestore query on that page to QuerySnapshot snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection("products").getDocuments. it also loads all the 20 documents but when I navigate back to main screen, instead of loading only the 7, it loads all the 20 until I refresh the page before it comes back to 7.. Any help

Comment: Please I have edited the question with the code. I am using Provider package.Thanks